# Azure WebJob vs App Service Date Format Issue with EF and SQL Azure

Tags: entity-framework, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs

I've hit upon an issue concerning a difference in the way dates are inserted into an SQL Azure database between WebJobs and App Services.

(I'm using British date format dd/mm/yyyy).

I have a repository class `TestRepository` that uses Entity Framework to insert records in to a SQL Azure database. One of the columns is a SQL `datetime` field.

```
public class TestRepository : RepositoryBase, ITestRepository
{
    public void ProcessTestXml(string xml)
    {
        var testResultParser = new TestResultParser(xml);
        var testResults = testResultParser.TestResults;

        using (var transactionScope = new TransactionScope())
        {
            var unitOfWork = new Entities();

            var test = new Test
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                TestNumber = testResults.TestNumber,
                PartNumber = testResults.Part,
                SerialNumber = testResults.SerialNumber,
                Started = testResults.StartDate
            };
            unitOfWork.Tests.Add(test);

            unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
            transactionScope.Complete();
        }
    }
}
```

The `TestResultParser.TestResults` is of this type:

```
public class TestResult
{
    public int TestNumber { get; set; }
    public string Part { get; set; }
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the EF POCO and code first map:

```
public partial class Test
{
    public System.Guid Id { get; set; }
    public byte[] Timestamp { get; set; }
    [Index]
    public DateTime Started { get; set; }
    public string PartNumber { get; set; }
    public string TestNumber { get; set; }
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
}

public class TestMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Test>
{
    public TestMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.Id);

        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.Id);

        this.Property(t => t.Timestamp)
            .IsRequired()
            .IsFixedLength()
            .HasMaxLength(8)
            .IsRowVersion();

        this.Property(t => t.PartNumber)
            .HasMaxLength(50);

        this.Property(t => t.TestNumber)
            .HasMaxLength(50);

        this.Property(t => t.SerialNumber)
            .HasMaxLength(50);
    }
}
```

The SQL column type for the `Started` field is `datetime`.

The parser builds the `TestResult` class. You'll notice the `StartDate` property is a DateTime. The parser works correctly - the date is always right in this field.

When I use the repository class to add records from within my App Service (MVC), everything works fine. The dates are entered correctly. However, when the same repository class is hosted within a WebJob attached to the **same** App Service slot, the dates end up in American format (mm/dd/yy).

As an added bonus, if the date is invalid in that format (e.g. 13/01/16) it then miraculously reverts to British format! I know, you couldn't make it up.

If I host the repository class inside a plain console app on my PC, with a local connection string, everything works fine. And with the connection string pointing to the Azure database, it still works fine. But as soon as I host the repository in a WebJob in the cloud, it exhibits the behaviour mentioned.

So any ideas?

Comment: Are you using the same webapp for the MVC website and the webjob ?

Comment: Yes! The webjob is attached to the same MVC app.

Comment: Can you post your code please ?

Comment: Added code, updated my question. Thanks.

Comment: I have tested to use EF to save datetime to Azure sql database, both Azure Web app & webjobs save the correct datetime. If change the system local, the output datetime will be different. If your web app &webjobs use the same database, do you mean there will be two format datetime in your database?

Comment: Its been a few years but did you ever get to the bottom of this?

Having a similar issue in one of our projects - two deployments of one web worker (Same code), One is using US dates and one is using UK,